# How To Get Custom Wordpress Page Template Conditionally

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, query-string, custom-post-type

I'm trying to alter the experience of the user by changing the page templates based on URL UTM variables.

Example, if the utm_source=google I want to show the person the page-google.php.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
    <?php if ( isset( $_GET['utm_source'] ) && $_GET['utm_source'] == 'test' ) 
{ 
get_page_template(test);
}
else {
    get_page_template(gallery);
}

?>
```

I'm not sure 1) if this is the right way 2) where it should be placed in wordpress.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in page.php

```
<?php if ( isset( $_GET['utm_source'] ) && $_GET['utm_source'] == 'test' ) { 
    get_template_part('test');
}
else {
    get_template_part('gallery');
}
?>
```

this is if test.php is in your sites theme directory

Comment: So there is another way that I figured out how to do this, but again it only lasts on the first page load. Adding this to functions.php

`<?php

function sjc_add_query_vars($vars) {
    return array('utm_source') + $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'sjc_add_query_vars');

?>

<?php
function sjc_template($template) {
  global $wp;
  if ($wp->query_vars['utm_source']=='taboola') {
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/page-gallery2.php';
  }
  else {
    return $template;
  }
}
add_filter('single_template', 'sjc_template');
?>`